# bubble sort and foreach index

Tags: c#

I have some code below for a button click event, 
which uses bubble sort. I am a little bit unclear 
of the use. Trying to sort an array in ascending 
order. Also I have to use a foreach and need to 
get an index from it some how. 
An attempt int z = a.GetEnumerator(); does not work. int k = 0;//Cheat to get code working

```
        int k = 0;//Cheat to get code working
        foreach (BankAccount BankAccount in a)
        //for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            //int z = a.GetEnumerator();
            lstBefore.Items.Add(a[k].show());
            k += 1;//Cheat to get code working
        }
        //if (a[0] is IComparable)
        //{
            //Sort.BubbleSort(a);//Sort a
            k = 0;//Cheat to get code working
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                lstAfter.Items.Add(a[k].show());
                //else MessageBox.Show("unable to sort");
                k += 1;//Cheat to get code working
            }
        //}
        //else MessageBox.Show("unable to sort");

class Sort : IComparable
{
    public static void BubbleSort(IComparable[] arr)
    {
        bool swap = true;
        IComparable temp;
        for (int i = 0; swap; i++)
        {
            swap = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < (arr.Length - (i + 1)); j++)
            {
                //int test = arr[j].CompareTo(arr[j + 1]);                    
                if (arr[j].CompareTo(arr[j + 1]) > 0)
                //If this balance is < than next balance                    
                {
                    temp = (IComparable)arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = temp;
                    swap = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also I have

```
public class BankAccount : IComparable, IComparable<BankAccount>//Class BackAccount -             //Icomarable    
{
    private decimal balance;
    private string FullName;
    //...

    public int CompareTo(BankAccount that)//Compare To        
    {
        if (this.balance > that.balance) return -1;//If this balance is > than next balance            
        if (this.balance == that.balance) return 0;//If this balance is = to next balance            
        return 1;//If this balance is < than next balance            
        //return this.balance.CompareTo(that.balance);        
    }
}
Thanks,
```

Comment: Yes, this is better right

Comment: Your `CompareTo` is backwards. It should return `1` if `this.balance > that.balance`. Unless you want it to sort backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to implement `CompareTo` in your `Sort` class (not just the `BankAccount` class).

Comment: Do you mean add a CompareTo method to he class Sort?

Answer (score 0):

First, a `foreach` does not have an index in any way. If you need a index, use a for loop.
Second, The `Sort` class have not to implement `IComparable` (which causes the error). It's a Comparer, not compared. It can implement `IComparer` if you want to, or to be static.
And why do you diving into bubble sort implementation, when you have `Array.Sort` or `List.Sort` methods, that implements QuickSort and is sure faster and better? I would avoided this.

Comment: Maybe he's learning about sorting algorithms and wants to see bubble sort in action.

Comment: Yeh, same with for each. I have to Write a method called ShowAccounts that uses the foreach construct to display each element in the array. and Use the BubbleSort with IComparable to sort accounts by balance amounts in ascending order.

Comment: I have for example new BankAccount("Micky Mouse", 900m) and have to sort on balance amount.

Comment: Keeping a index variable and advancing it, like you did, is the normal way to have a index in a foreach loop. As for `IComparable`, they meant that `BankAccount` need to be IComparable in order to be sorted, not `Sort` class, which is not 'comparable'.